# Copy part of array to itself?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

Basically I'm building a bit reader, slightly before the buffer has been exhausted, I'd like to copy whatever is left of the array to the beginning of the same array, and then zero everything after the copy, and fill the rest with data from the input file.

I'm only trying to use the standard library for portability reasons.

Also, I was profiling my bit reader earlier and Instruments says it was taking like 28 milliseconds to do all of this, is it supposed to take that long?

Code removed

Comment: Although I'm starting to think I should just skip all of this, and instead rewind the file to the last unread byte and simply read from there until the buffer is full...

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See `memcpy` (if there's no overlap) or `memmove` (if there could be overlap). Also 28 ms is meaningless unless you give us some idea of the input size you're dealing with, the hardware you're running this on, etc.

Comment: I'll edit with an example 1 sec.

Comment: @Ike The InputBuffer is 4096 bytes, not exactly a huge data set. in fact it *should* be exactly one page of memory on most systems.

Comment: The declaration `FILE InputFile` seems very strange, given that `fopen` returns a `FILE *`, and `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are also `FILE *`.

Comment: That's actually a typo, my struct has a bunch of redundant crap so I just thought I'd write pseudo code to get the point across.

Comment: @MarcusJ If it isn't an MCVE, you should probably just leave it out. Your question should either stand without an MCVE (which, in my opinion, it does) or, in this case, should include a testcase that compiles and produces your problem (e.g. a testcase that you have compiled and produces 28 milliseconds, that we can also run and produce 28 milliseconds, given the implementation that you're targetting, which is also information that we'd need)...

Comment: @MarcusJ 28 ms to process a 4 KB buffer does sound pretty gross unless you do extremely intensive computation on it, but does that include the time to open the file and so forth? Anyway, that might be better off as a follow-up question where you provide much more details about exactly what you are doing (ideally some source code too) and want to know how to optimize it. Your starting point for this one is `memmove` or `memcpy`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it includes time to open the file, but the second time I call ReadBits it's around 4 ms, which still seems like a lot, that's billions of CPU instructions, but whateve.

Comment: I mean, I'll post my code for ReadBits, but there's a LOT of cruft from previous attempts, and it's not nearly complete.

Comment: I've cleaned p my code, but now I'm having an issue with the for loop to actually read the bits. when reading 64 bits it works fine, when reading less than that it loops once too many times.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using `memmove` for the copy. It has a signature and functionality identical to `memcpy`, except that it is safe for copying between overlapping regions (which is what you're describing).

For the zero-fill, `memset` is usually adequate. On the occasion where null pointers aren't represented using an underlying sequence of zeros, for example, you'll need to roll your own using assignment depending upon the type.

For this reason you might want to hide the `memmove` and `memset` operations behind abstraction, for example:

```
#include <string.h>

void copy_int(int *destination, int *source, size_t size) {
    memmove(destination, source, size * sizeof *source);
}

void zero_int(int *seq, size_t size) {
    memset(seq, 0, size * sizeof *seq);
}

int main(void) {
    int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    size_t index = 2
         , size  = sizeof array / sizeof *array - index;
    copy_int(array, array + index, size);
    zero_int(array + size, index);
}
```

Should either `memmove` or `memset` become unsuitable for usecases in the future, it'll then be simple to drop in your own copy/zero loops.

As for your strange profiler results, I suppose it might be possible that you're using some archaic (or grossly underclocked) implementation, or trying to copy huge arrays... Otherwise, 28 milliseconds does seem quite absurd. Nonetheless, your profiler would have surely identified that this `memmove` and `memset` isn't a significant bottleneck in an a program that performs actual I/O work, right? The I/O must surely be the bottleneck, right?

If the `memmove`+`memset` is indeed a bottleneck, you could try implementing a circular array to avoid the copies. For example, the following code attempts to find `needle` in the figurative haystack that is `input_file`...

Otherwise, if the I/O is a bottleneck, there are tweaks that can be applied to reduce that. For example, the following code uses `setvbuf` to suggest that the underlying implementation attempt to use an underlying buffer to read chunks of the file, despite the code using `fgetc` to read one character at a time.

```
void find_match(FILE *input_file, char const *needle, size_t needle_size) {
    char input_array[needle_size];
    size_t sz = fread(input_array, 1, needle_size, input_file);
    if (sz != needle_size) {
        // No matches possible
        return;
    }

    setvbuf(input_file, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
    unsigned long long pos = 0;
    for (;;) {
        size_t cursor = pos % needle_size;
        int tail_compare = memcmp(input_array, needle + needle_size - cursor, cursor),
            head_compare = memcmp(input_array + cursor, needle, needle_size - cursor);
        if (head_compare == 0 && tail_compare == 0) {
            printf("Match found at offset %llu\n", pos);
        }
        int c = fgetc(input_file);
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        input_array[cursor] = c;
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Notice how there's no `memmove` (or zeroing, FWIW) necessary here? We simply operate as though the start of the array is at `cursor`, the end at `cursor - 1` and we wrap by modulo `needle_size` to ensure there's no overflow/underflow. Then, after each insertion we simply increment the `cursor`...